# Convert xml file to Java object using Jaxb

Tags: xml, jaxb

How to create java object from this xml file using JAXB,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Parameters>
<Varremise>
     <Name>Amazigh</Name>
     <Var>Notprovided</Var>
     <Var>Notprovided</Var>     
</Varremise>
<Varheader>
     <Name>CdAppOr</Name>
     <Var>P</Var>
     <Var>A</Var>
     <Var>O</Var>
</Varheader>
<Vardetail>
     <Name>TopUC</Name>
     <Var>U</Var>
     <Var>C</Var>
</Vardetail>
</Parameters>
```

i have try with this but it dont work,

Parameters class :

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "parametersContainer")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Parameters")
public class Parameters {

@XmlElement(name = "Varremise")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Varremise")
private Set<VarRemise> varremise;

@XmlElement(name = "Varheader")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Varheader")
private Set<VarHeader> varheader;

@XmlElement(name = "Vardetail")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Vardetail")
private Set<VarDetail> vardetail;


public Set<VarHeader> getVarheader() {
    return varheader;
}

public void setVarheader(final Set<VarHeader> varheader) {
    this.varheader = varheader;
}

public Set<VarDetail> getVardetail() {
    return vardetail;
}

public void setVardetail(final Set<VarDetail> vardetail) {
    this.vardetail = vardetail;
}

public Set<VarRemise> getVarremise() {
    return varremise;
}

public void setVarremise(final Set<VarRemise> varremise) {
    this.varremise = varremise;
}

}
```

AllVarsDefinition class :

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AllVarsDefinition {

@XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
private String name;

@XmlElement(name = "Var", required = true)
private Set<String> var;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<String> getVar() {
    return var;
}

public void setVar(final Set<String> var) {
    this.var = var;
}

}
```

VarHeader class :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VarHeader extends AllVarsDefinition {

}
```

the same code to Vardetail and varRemise classes,

When i excute this code it create an empty object

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Parameters")
public class Parameters {


@XmlElement(name = "Varremise")
private List<VarRemise> varremise;


public List<VarRemise> getVarremise() {
    return varremise;
}

public void setVarremise(final List<VarRemise> varremise) {
    this.varremise = varremise;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Varheader")
private List<VarHeader> varheader;

@XmlElement(name = "Vardetail")
private List<VarDetail> vardetail;

public List<VarHeader> getVarheader() {
    return varheader;
}

public void setVarheader(final List<VarHeader> varheader) {
    this.varheader = varheader;
}

public List<VarDetail> getVardetail() {
    return vardetail;
}

public void setVardetail(final List<VarDetail> vardetail) {
    this.vardetail = vardetail;
}

}
```

VarRemise class

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VarRemise {


@XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
private String name;

@XmlElement(name = "Var", required = true)
private Set<String> vars;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<String> getVars() {
    return vars;
}

public void setVars(final Set<String> vars) {
    this.vars = vars;
}

}
```

The same code to vardetail and varhead class, and it work

Thank you cvesters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your XML is not what is expected.
You have specified a wrapper and an element with the same name.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Varheader")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Varheader")
```

The xml expected actually is of the form:

```
<Varheader>
    <Varheader></Varheader>
</Varheader>
```

**EDIT:**

Based on some comments the solution should be:

- Remove the WrapperElements
- Change the Set to List as JAXB will automatically parse lists this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Now it return null, not empty object

Comment: I don't think removing the wrapper solves all problems. I don't think you can now specify more than 1 element in the list. Maybe you should try that.

Comment: Yes, it get juste the first Element

Comment: Can you post your new code? With the wrappers. (which returned null)

Comment: i have juste change the name of Wrapper and it return null

Comment: @XmlElement(name = "Varremise")
 @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Varremises")
 private Set<VarRemise> varremise;

Comment: are you still using the same xml file?

Comment: Yes, when i try to display on console content  of the only element that it return, it display blank (empty char)

Comment: Your xml needs to change now too... as you have specified the wrapper.
<Varremises>
    <Varremise>
        <Name>
    </Varremise>
</Varremises>

Comment: i can't change the xml file, I must consume the xml file that is made by the client

Comment: I quickly did some research, and it should work if you change the Set to List.

Comment: i'll see this with the client, thank for your answers sir cvesters

Comment: i can't change the xml file structure

Comment: In that case you should just convert the Set to a List. I believe that will solve the issue as well. But you have to drop the WrapperElements (See the Edit)

Comment: I have found solution, it very easy, i shre it now